# Java printing : which DocFlavor to choose for my printer?

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to print a text file with java print on my printer CANON MB5000.
It works on Linux but not on Windows.
On windows here are the doc flavor supported :

```
for (DocFlavor f : printService.getSupportedDocFlavors()){
                System.out.println("media type : "+f.getMediaType());
                System.out.println("mime type : "+f.getMimeType());
            }
```

I am getting:

```
media type : image
mime type : image/gif
media type : image
mime type : image/gif
media type : image
mime type : image/gif
media type : image
mime type : image/jpeg
media type : image
mime type : image/jpeg
media type : image
mime type : image/jpeg
media type : image
mime type : image/png
media type : image
mime type : image/png
media type : image
mime type : image/png
media type : application
mime type : application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref
media type : application
mime type : application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref
media type : application
mime type : application/octet-stream
media type : application
mime type : application/octet-stream
media type : application
mime type : application/octet-stream
```

I have tried to print with octet-stream :

```
    if (service != null){
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:/mytxt.txt");
        Doc pdfDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, new DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM ("application/octet-stream"), null);
        DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();
        printJob.print(pdfDoc, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
        fis.close();
    }
```

Nothing prints.
If I use new DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM ("image/jpeg") and if I print a JPEG image, it works.
What should I do in order to be able to print a Text file (or PDF file)?

Comment: Did you happen to look at the [documentation for the DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.html)?  There are a lot of predefined DocFlavors present as static constants, including constants for each of the types you mention, as well as AUTOSENSE.

Comment: yes, but I have tried with AUTOSENSE, which is supposed to work with octet-stream, but nothing prints with AUTOSENSE

Comment: And what about the others?  DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_HOST?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure , but guess a way around would be application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref;class="java.awt.print.Pageable" or
application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref;class="java.awt.print.Printable". Maybe for pdf can be something like reuse https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/printing/Printing.java?view=markup) or if don't want to add external dependency, create UDT that implements Printable and Pageable interface... Hope this helps.